# FFMPEG: create movie from timestamped images

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, jpeg, mjpeg

Im trying to make a small movie file from a folder with webcam images.

They are named like this:
00-00-38.jpg
00-05-37.jpg
00-10-37.jpg
00-15-37.jpg

H-M-S.jpg  format

Although i tried patterntype glob and simpler commands i cannot get it to work.

This is what i tried:

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -scale=720:-1 -c:v libx264 out.mp4 
(got only one image)
ffmpeg -r 25 -i *.jpg -vf "scale=720:-1" output.mp4
(same size as a jpg file but no video)
```

Console output:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -vf scale=720:-1 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
    ffmpeg version 1.0.10 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers  built on Jul 25 2014 07:50:40 with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
      configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' 
    --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro' --cc='ccache cc' --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libvorbis 
    --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-libtheora --enable-li
    bopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --enable-libvpx --
    enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --enable-version3 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-avfilter --
    enable-libfreetype --enable-libvo-aacenc --disable-decoder=amrnb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libaacplus --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64
    -linux-gnu --disable-vda --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-gnutls --enable-frei0r --enable-openssl --enable-libass --enabl
    e-libopus --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libdc1394 --disable-altivec --dis
      libavutil      51. 73.101 / 51. 73.101
      libavcodec     54. 59.100 / 54. 59.100
      libavformat    54. 29.104 / 54. 29.104
      libavdevice    54.  2.101 / 54.  2.101
      libavfilter     3. 17.100 /  3. 17.100
      libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
      libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
      libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
    [image2 @ 0x1d53f00] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5000000
    Input #0, image2, from '*.jpg':
      Duration: 00:04:48.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
        Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 800x593 [SAR 96:96 DAR 800:593], 1 fps, 1 tbr, 1 tbn, 1 tbc
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] using SAR=1780/1779
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX XOP FMA4 FMA3 SSEMisalign LZCNT BMI1
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] profile High, level 2.2
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] 264 - core 132 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options:  ca
    bac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dc
    t=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=
    0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 key
    int_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=
    1:1.00
    Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavf54.29.104
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 720x534 [SAR 1780:1779 DAR 800:593], q=-1--1, 1 tbn, 1 tbc
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> libx264)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    frame=  288 fps=145 q=32763.0 Lsize=     349kB time=00:04:46.00 bitrate=  10.0kbits/s
    video:345kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.208469%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] frame I:2     Avg QP: 2.80  size:130328
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] frame P:73    Avg QP: 4.70  size:  1167
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] frame B:213   Avg QP:17.33  size:    30
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] consecutive B-frames:  1.4%  0.0%  0.0% 98.6%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] mb I  I16..4: 20.2% 24.9% 55.0%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  4.3%  0.1%  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:95.5%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.8%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.2%  L0: 5.4% L1:94.5% BI: 0.0
    %
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] 8x8 transform intra:24.9% inter:51.5%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 99.4% 0.0% 0.0% inter: 0.6% 0.0% 0.0%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] i16 v,h,dc,p:  5% 19% 52% 25%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 10% 28% 21%  4%  6%  4%  8%  5% 15%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 14% 27% 13%  6%  8%  5%  9%  6% 12%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 100%  0%  0%  0%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] ref P L0: 98.1%  0.0%  1.7%  0.2%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] ref B L0: 52.0% 48.0%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] ref B L1: 73.0% 27.0%
    [libx264 @ 0x1d35bc0] kb/s:9.78
```

The video is 364KB without any video.

Comment: Take a look at: [Create a video slideshow from images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images).

Comment: Been there done that:)

Comment: It looks like it is successfully writing several frames.  Perhaps the problem is your video player.  Try `ffplay` which comes with FFmpeg.  Also try `-framerate 25` as some players have problems with very low frame rates.  Also FFmpeg 1.0.10 is not maintained any more; try FFmpeg 2.5.4 or a snapshot or static build from http://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: I downloaded this version from the ffmpeg repo today, maybe they are not serving the correct one. (Debian Wheezy). Tried several different players, VLC, WMP, W8 Video, Adobe Aftereffects. Still i can see only one image. The time in the movie seems correct but only one image visisble (the first one on disk)

Comment: 1.0.10 is very old.  A static binary that will work on Debian can be downloaded from the above link to try out the current version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -vf scale=720:-1 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

If that doesn't work for you, include the exact command you used and the full console output indicating what is wrong.

Comment: added the output above, i get a 364KB file with no video in it.

Comment: it seems it only loads one jpg file and it ignores the rest

Comment: @HyperDevil According to what player(s)? What about `ffplay`?

Comment: I used several different ones, VLC, WMP, W8 Video etc.. i can only see one frame.

Answer (score 0):

I've always done something along the lines of:

```
a=0
for i in *.jpg; do
    new=$(printf "/home/Movies/jpgs/%04d.jpg" "$a")
    cp -f "$i" "$new"
    let a=a+1
done
```

to get the files in the right order, anything else breaks the encoding as soon as the input numbers are non-monotonic.